# How to show newly downloaded files in folder 'Downloads' in file manager 'Dolphin'?

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-studio, dolphin, plasma-5

Recently, I upgraded my Ubuntu Studio system from version 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS, and suddenly, newly downloaded files are not shown in real-time in the new default file manager named 'Dolphin'.

To see newly downloaded files or newly taken screenshots, that I save in the folder 'Downloads' too, I have to close the file manager completely and then reopen it to see these new files. Why this file manager isn't capable of showing new files instantly without closing and reopening the file manager?

Very frustrating!

With my old version of Ubuntu Studio there was no such problem at all with the then default file manager 'Thunar'.

---

System informations:

- Linux/KDE Plasma: Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Dolphin Version: 21.12.3

---

Addendum #1:

I just realized, that the icon of the folder 'Downloads' on my Desktop doesn't show the preview of the first 4 files shown in this folder-icon in real-time too, and needs another hit on the F5-button, when the Desktop-surface is activated/maximized. That said, hitting F5 in the file manager 'Dolphin' does not refresh the preview of the correspondent folder-icon on the Desktop at the same time. I don't know if this problem is just the file manager 'Dolphin' or is there a higher level problem in the Desktop settings (= KDE Plasma)?

---

Addendum #2:

Last night shortly after midnight I manually updated my recently upgraded system for the first time with ...

**1. 'Software Updater'** listing 2 files to update:

- 'Emoji-Auswahl' (43.2MB)
- 'Ubuntu-Studio-Kern' (1.4MB)

While the update-installation proceeded, I got a notification titled 'debconf-kde-helper - KDialog <2>' saying word-for-word (screenshot) ...

> > **'Configuration file "//.config/debconf-kde-helperrc" not writable. Please contact your system administrator.'**

**BTW, how can I get these configuration files permanently writable?**

Nevertheless, I could finish the installation process by clicking on the 'OK'-button in the notification-window.

I remember now, that I got a similar notification once during my system upgrade from version 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS, but could finish the upgrade process by clicking on the 'OK'-button, too.

Otherwise, never before I've got a notification like this updating Ubuntu Studio.

**2.  'Discover'** listing 9 files to update:

- 'kde-config-updates 5.24.6-0ubuntu.0.1 -> 5.24.7-0ubuntu.0.1' (16.9KiB)
- etc.

The installation process of these 9 files finished smoothly without any notification.

After that 'Systemsettings' > 'About this system' > '**KDE-Plasma-Version**' has changed from 5.24.6 to **5.24.7**.

And suddenly, **there is AUTO-refresh** in the file manager 'Dolphin'.
It is **not just yet working 100% reliable** (I would rate it 80% reliable). I tested intensely for at least one hour (taking dozens of screenshots, saving them in different folders, opening/closing file manager 'Dolphin', rebooting system), but I could not identify a repeatable pattern. Now, at this point in time it seems random to me. Of all the tested folders the folder 'Downloads' is the most affected by not beeing refreshed in real-time (estimated 50/50% reliable). Maybe this is also correlated to the on/off split-view setting or maybe to the active(= blue-lined)/non-active split-view?

Comment: You read the Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS Release notes or upgrade instructions (https://ubuntustudio.org/2022/04/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-released/ etc) as they clearly stated "*Due to the change in desktop environment that started after the release of 20.04 LTS, direct upgrades from 20.04 LTS are not supported and may only be attempted at-your-own-risk.*"

Comment: Thank you 'guiverc'! Also, they stated clearly '... it is highly recommended to wait until 22.04.1 is released in August before attempting such an upgrade.' - what I did. Honestly, closing and reopening the file manager each time to see new files isn't acceptable, even after a system upgrade with major changes. My 2 cents. Would be 'nice' to have a solution for this basic problem.

Comment: I don't use Dolphin...but just wondering if hitting `F5` will refresh the list of files?

Comment: @Ray Yes, it will. It is also possible to add a `Refresh`-button to the toolbar.

Comment: @Novice In a fresh install there is not such a problem, downloaded files will be displayed immediately, no need to refresh the list.

Comment: SOLUTION for MANUAL-Refresh with F5-button works great, just us adding the Refresh-button to the toolbar in Dolphin. Very helpful - 'Ray' and 'mook765' - very appreciated!

Comment: Q.: Is there any solution for an AUTO-Refresh available to be fully productive without hitting the F5-button?

Comment: Note that you can also change that shortcut or add a second one in Dolphin's Settings-Configure keyboard shortcuts, including to one-key one.

Comment: FYI:  I did a test for this last night when I read & left my first comment; with `dolphin` opened and viewing the ~/Downloads folder; a download via my browser of my icon on this page showed instantly.   The upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1 is **not** supported due to DE change & breakage, the prior comment highlights issues; Lubuntu didn't support LXDE to LXQt change of DE either.. Your old configs need to be manually corrected due to your *release-upgrade* & change of DE; 20.04 was the last Xfce of Studio & *end-of-the-road* without clean install as was warned only weeks post 20.04's release

Comment: FYI:  The release notes for 20.04 (https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-lts-released/) warned you wouldn't be able to *release-upgrade* too.  "*Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS will be the final release of Ubuntu Studio using the Xfce Desktop Environment. As such, upgrades from Ubuntu Studio 20.04 to later releases may result in breakage.*"

Comment: @cipricus Thank you very much for your information. Very appreciated! What does the last part of the sentence '... one-key one.' mean?

Comment: You can set a single key (like S for split-view or F for full-screen) as shortcut, not just a combination of key+modifier (Shift, Alt, Shift, Super) as it usually is the rule. But you might not want that: it interferes with other uses of a key, for example, by default when you have multiple files in the file manager and you press S, a file or folder with the name starting with S is selected: you lose that if you set S for split-view. It depends on what you prefer to have. I use 1-key shortcuts in Dolphin  because for selection I use the filter (Ctrl+I). I also do it in Okular.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much for your very interesting background informations. Very appreciated! In my defence as an ordinary Linux user with very little experience in the Linux world since roughly 3 years, I did what these continuous notifications at the end of my weekly updates ask for months: Do you want to upgrade your installation from version 20.04 to version 22.04, later on I was asked to version 22.04.1. I waited nearly 8 months before upgrading last week in mid November. If basically, this upgrade is not possible, I think, Ubuntu Studio should/would not send these notifications.

Comment: @guiverc BTW, all went very smoothly without crash. Kudos to the whole Ubuntu (Studio) team! With the newly learned keyword 'Refresh', I found several posts indicating that this problem seems to frustrate other users and even 'Art Directors', too ...
https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/dolphin-file-browser-refresh-not-real-time/9846/5
'It has existed since at least 2013, and users have been pressing F5 since 2013 ...'
The big QUESTION now is, how to correct/fix the old configs manually as you mentioned in your previous comment to get AUTO-Refresh in the file manager 'Dolphin'?

Comment: @cipricus Thank you very much for your further detailed hands-on explanations. Very helpful!

Comment: look into Dolphin settings for many other interesting stuff: for example, the split-view once active can be toggled off with the same key but it closes the selected or the other pane, depending on the setting, and there is also an option so that Tab key can be used to switch pane selection. Also; toolbar buttons can be added and removed, but their names and icons can be changed too. the bug affecting refresh is too bad, old, I have it too but it stopped bothering me once I know of it.

Comment: @cipricus Thank you very much for your helpful leads! Hitting F5 to refresh the file manager or the folder-icon on the Desktop here and there, I start to get used to it, too ;-)